# disable temporary autoconf inet6 address

Tags: network, sleep-wake, ssh, system-settings, ipv6

My OS X machine gets assigned two public IP addresses from [Android 7.1.1](//android.stackexchange.com/questions/181361/does-android-have-support-for-ipv6-tethering/190926#190926):

```
% ifconfig en0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 8c:29:XX:XX:XX:XX 
    inet6 fe80::8e29:XXff:feXX:XXXX%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.43.163 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255
    inet6 2607:fb90:4bYY:YYYY:8e29:XXff:feXX:XXXX prefixlen 64 autoconf 
    inet6 2607:fb90:4bYY:YYYY:d427:13ba:ZZZZ:ZZZZ prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

The problem I've encountered is that the `temporary` one may change with sleep/wake, whereas the permanent one still has the prefix that is not guaranteed to stay the same (it depends on ME).

I want to use the non-temporary address for [`ssh`](http://mdoc.su/o/ssh.1), or, at least, extend the time during which the `temporary` address stays the same (e.g., let's say, to get it automatically hardcoded until the /64 prefix gets reassigned upstream).  How?!

As a sidenote, I'm trying to make it easier to identify my ssh connections from within the cloud, as well as make my `ssh` connections not break between short sleeps; it seems there's an [`ssh_config(5)` option called ***`BindAddress`***](http://mdoc.su/o/ssh_config.5#BindAddress), and it does appear to work (`ssh -oBindAddress=2607:fb90:4b61:7474:8e29:XXff:feXX:XXXX …`), but I'd prefer to have this configured without hardcoding the prefix that's still temporary in nature.  E.g., the solution I'm looking for likely involves system preferences; it's OK if it's not exclusive to ssh.

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question on SuperUser](//superuser.com/questions/645205/disable-ipv6-autoconf-mac-based-ipv6-address-without-disabling-privacy-address) prompted me to look into [sysctl](http://mdoc.su/f/sysctl.3) settings, with the following setting available to prefer the permanent IPv6 autoconf addresses to the temporary ones:

```
% sudo sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.prefer_tempaddr=0
Password:
net.inet6.ip6.prefer_tempaddr: 1 -> 0
%
```

For ssh sessions that aren't expecting any ongoing interaction, this would make it possible to go to sleep, and wake up within a number of minutes without any SSH connections suffering a disconnect (which would previously happen due to the prior IPv6 address being de-provisioned upon the wakeup from sleep).   *(Don't need no [mosh](http://ports.su/net/mosh)!)*